# Start a new PostgreSQL instance on an existing data dir

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to copy a PostgreSQL data dir from a disk (without backup) and use it with a new instance in another server ?

I loose my system but I can access data dir (data_directory)...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried installing PostgreSQL on the new server, replacing the data dir with the one from the crashed system, and restarting PostgreSQL? If that doesn't work, here is an article on changing the data directory for a postgres instance: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I've done this a number of times, yes it can be done quite easily. 1. Install postgres. 2. Stop the service. 3. Replace the newly created data folder with your own copy. 4. Start the service. Done.